# Why Does "mainloop()" For One Window Open Multiple Windows?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm using Tkinter. For whatever reason, "Window1.mainloop()" in this script opens both Window1 and Window2. Also, pressing the button on Window1 doesn't open Window2, but I think that's unrelated.

```
import tkinter as tk

Window1 = tk.Tk()
Window1.title("Window 1")
Window1.geometry("300x200")

Window2 = tk.Tk()
Window2.title("Window 2")
Window2.geometry("150x100")

def RunWindow2():
    Window2.mainloop()

Button1 = tk.Button(Window1, text = "Open Window 2.", command = RunWindow2)
Button1.pack()

Label1 = tk.Label(Window2, text = "This is Window 2.")
Label1.pack()

Window1.mainloop()
```

Comment: `Window2 = tk.Tk()` creates a new window and opens it. Move all the `Window2` and `Label1` code into the `RunWindow2()` function.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Thanks! That fixed it! But why did "mainloop()" for one window open both?

Comment: `mainloop()` didn't open the window. `Window2 = tk.Tk()` did.

Comment: @Redcoolhax Also as long as you have 1 tkinter window open `.mainloop()` will never stop running so you only really need 1 `.mainloop()` call not matter how many `Tk()` and `Toplevel()` object you have

Comment: @TheLizzard Oh, so basically "mainloop()" just keeps the windows running just as long as one of them is open?

Comment: @Redcoolhax Kind of. It handles all of the events like mouse presses and keyboard presses for as long as there is at lest 1 tkinter window open.

Comment: @TheLizzard Oh. Okay. Thanks!